specman: how to connect event_port in a unit to an event in another unit?
I have a unit with an event port:
unit phy_master_core_arbiter_u {
in_clk_sig: in event_port is instance;
event in_clk is @in_clk_sig$ ;keep bind(in_clk_sig, external);
...
}
another unit has an instance of the above unit, and has an event clk_e:
unit phy_master_bfm_u like uvm_bfm {
event clk_e is rise (p_smp.clk$) @sim;
core_arbiters[4] : list of phy_master_core_arbiter_u is instance;
}
how to set the hdl_path of the event port to point on the clk_e event?
I tried to do it in the agent that instance the above bfm but I got an error :
keep  bfm.core_arbiters[0].in_clk_sig.hdl_path() == append(bfm.full_hdl_path(),"/","clk_e");

To solve it :

add:  out event_port to unit phy_master_bfm_u.
in the phy_master agent , connect between the ports using keep bind

